# Creating mysql driver for Qt 6.5.1

Tags: mysql, qt, compilation, driver, qmake

[image: 1]

I have confirmed that those folders have all the necessary dile like mysql.h, libmysql.lib, libmysql.dll.
But when ever I try to run this qmake code, it does nothing but just show this texts. How can I fix this?
I tried to copy those necessay files in mysql\c++ connectore.. folders too but it didn't work.

I tried to create mysql driver for my qt project. And I was expecting to have a mysql driver in ...\sr\lpugins\sqldrivers folder.

Comment: Since Qt6 does not use qmake as buildsystem but cmake you have to use cmake here as properly explained in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/sql-driver.html#compile-only-a-specific-sql-driver)

Comment: I tried this -
"qt-cmake -G Ninja <qt_installation_path>\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<qt_installation_path>\<platform> -DMySQL_INCLUDE_DIR="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include" -DMySQL_LIBRARY="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\libmysql.lib"

Comment: But it is saying- "The system cannot find the file specified."